# Trust fall homicide

Tags: united-states, homicide

If I have established with another person that I will catch him as he voluntarily falls backward ("trust" falls), what are the legal ramifications for me (in the US) if I don't catch him and he breaks his neck and dies?

Comment: Do you intentionally fail to catch the person, or is it accidental (you were distracted)? Are you capable of actually catching them or is it beyond your abilities (a toddler being asked to catch a grown man) and did the person doing the falling know about this in advance?

Comment: I am capable, and the lack of action is intentional.

Answer (score 2):

The facts would probably support a conviction for manslaughter; you cause the death of another person through recklessness. If a motive could be established so that it could be shown that you planned to cause the person's death in this manner then a murder charge could be proved.

Comment: dont you think it would matter what kind of "trust" was established?  I mean, if the truster knew there was a possibility of not being caught, then the trustee really can't be blamed, can he?